# Create sentence (row) to POS tags counts (column) matrix from a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk, text-analysis

I am trying to build a matrix where the first row will be a part of speech, first column a sentence. values in the matrix should show the number of such POS in a sentence.

So I am creating POS tags in this way:

```
data = pd.read_csv(open('myfile.csv'),sep=';') 

target = data["label"]
del data["label"]

data.sentence = data.sentence.str.lower() # All strings in data frame to lowercase

for line in data.sentence:
    Line_new= nltk.pos_tag(nltk.word_tokenize(line))
    print(Line_new)
```

The output is:

```
[('together', 'RB'), ('with', 'IN'), ('the', 'DT'), ('6th', 'CD'), ('battalion', 'NN'), ('of', 'IN'), ('the', 'DT')]
```

How can I create a matrix which I have described above from such output?

UPDATE:
The desired output is

```
                   NN  VB    IN    VBZ    DT
 I was there       1   1     1      0     0
 He came there     0   0     1      1     1
```

myfile.csv:

```
"A child who is exclusively or predominantly oral (using speech for communication) can experience social isolation from his or her hearing peers, particularly if no one takes the time to explicitly teach them social skills that other children acquire independently by virtue of having normal hearing.";"certain"
"Preliminary Discourse to the Encyclopedia of Diderot";"certain"
"d'Alembert claims that it would be ignorant to perceive that everything could be known about a particular subject.";"certain"
"However, as the overemphasis on parental influence of psychodynamics theory has been strongly criticized in the previous century, modern psychologists adopted interracial contact as a more important determinant than childhood experience on shaping people’s prejudice traits (Stephan & Rosenfield, 1978).";"uncertain"
"this can also be summarized as a distinguish behaviour on the peronnel level";"uncertain"
```

Comment: What do you mean by a matrix? Could you specify and give an example of your desired output?

Comment: @alvas Thank you for your remark! Added the desired output at the end

Comment: How does your `'myfile.csv'` look like? Could you print the `data.head()`?

Comment: @alvas If I print `data.head()` than I see 2 columns: sentence and label. In sentence sentences are stored and in label one of two values — yes or no

Comment: I mean, could you show how the original `myfile.csv' looks like? Just show the top 5 rows would do.

Comment: @alvas Yes, sure. added to the main message in the post.

Comment: Just to double check, you don't need the POS information from `pos_tag` right? Since your desired output just needs the "bag-of-word" vector.

Comment: @alvas good that you have double checked it. Thank you! I did a mistake. I have edited it. Of course instead of words there are part of speeches.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**In Long:**

First let's add some headers to your csv so that it's more humanly-readable when accessing the columns:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv', delimiter=';')
>>> df.columns = ['sent', 'tag']
>>> df['sent']
0    Preliminary Discourse to the Encyclopedia of D...
1    d'Alembert claims that it would be ignorant to...
2    However, as the overemphasis on parental influ...
3    this can also be summarized as a distinguish b...
Name: sent, dtype: object
>>> df['tag']
0      certain
1      certain
2    uncertain
3    uncertain
```

Now let's create a function `tok_and_tag` that does `word_tokenize` and `pos_tag` in a chained manner:

```
>>> from nltk import word_tokenize, pos_tag
>>> from functools import partial
>>> tok_and_tag = lambda x: pos_tag(word_tokenize(x))
>>> df['sent'][0]
'Preliminary Discourse to the Encyclopedia of Diderot'
>>> tok_and_tag(df['sent'][0])
[('Preliminary', 'JJ'), ('Discourse', 'NNP'), ('to', 'TO'), ('the', 'DT'), ('Encyclopedia', 'NNP'), ('of', 'IN'), ('Diderot', 'NNP')]
```

Then, we can use [`df.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to tokenize and tag the sentence column of the dataframe:

```
>>> df['sent'].apply(tok_and_tag)
0    [(Preliminary, JJ), (Discourse, NNP), (to, TO)...
1    [(d'Alembert, NN), (claims, NNS), (that, IN), ...
2    [(However, RB), (,, ,), (as, IN), (the, DT), (...
3    [(this, DT), (can, MD), (also, RB), (be, VB), ...
Name: sent, dtype: object
```

If you want the sentences to be lowercased:

```
>>> df['sent'].apply(str.lower)
0    preliminary discourse to the encyclopedia of d...
1    d'alembert claims that it would be ignorant to...
2    however, as the overemphasis on parental influ...
3    this can also be summarized as a distinguish b...
Name: sent, dtype: object

>>> df['lower_sent'] = df['sent'].apply(str.lower)

>>> df['lower_sent'].apply(tok_and_tag)
0    [(preliminary, JJ), (discourse, NN), (to, TO),...
1    [(d'alembert, NN), (claims, NNS), (that, IN), ...
2    [(however, RB), (,, ,), (as, IN), (the, DT), (...
3    [(this, DT), (can, MD), (also, RB), (be, VB), ...
Name: lower_sent, dtype: object
```

Additionally, we need some sort of way to get the POS vocabulary, we can do use `collections.Counter` and `itertools.chain` to flatten the list of list:

```
>>> df['lower_sent']
0    preliminary discourse to the encyclopedia of d...
1    d'alembert claims that it would be ignorant to...
2    however, as the overemphasis on parental influ...
3    this can also be summarized as a distinguish b...
Name: lower_sent, dtype: object

>>> df['lower_sent'].apply(tok_and_tag)
0    [(preliminary, JJ), (discourse, NN), (to, TO),...
1    [(d'alembert, NN), (claims, NNS), (that, IN), ...
2    [(however, RB), (,, ,), (as, IN), (the, DT), (...
3    [(this, DT), (can, MD), (also, RB), (be, VB), ...
Name: lower_sent, dtype: object

>>> df['tagged_sent'] = df['lower_sent'].apply(tok_and_tag)

>>> tokens, tags = zip(*chain(*df['tagged_sent'].tolist()))

>>> tags
('JJ', 'NN', 'TO', 'DT', 'NN', 'IN', 'NN', 'NN', 'NNS', 'IN', 'PRP', 'MD', 'VB', 'JJ', 'TO', 'VB', 'IN', 'NN', 'MD', 'VB', 'VBN', 'IN', 'DT', 'JJ', 'NN', '.', 'RB', ',', 'IN', 'DT', 'NN', 'IN', 'JJ', 'NN', 'IN', 'NNS', 'NN', 'VBZ', 'VBN', 'RB', 'VBN', 'IN', 'DT', 'JJ', 'NN', ',', 'JJ', 'NNS', 'VBD', 'JJ', 'NN', 'IN', 'DT', 'RBR', 'JJ', 'NN', 'IN', 'NN', 'NN', 'IN', 'VBG', 'JJ', 'NN', 'NNS', '(', 'NN', 'CC', 'NN', ',', 'CD', ')', '.', 'DT', 'MD', 'RB', 'VB', 'VBN', 'IN', 'DT', 'JJ', 'NN', 'IN', 'DT', 'NNS', 'NN')

>>> set(tags)
{'CC', 'VB', ')', 'NNS', ',', 'JJ', 'VBZ', 'DT', 'NN', 'PRP', 'RBR', 'TO', 'VBD', '(', 'VBN', '.', 'MD', 'IN', 'RB', 'VBG', 'CD'}
>>> possible_tags = sorted(set(tags))
>>> possible_tags
['(', ')', ',', '.', 'CC', 'CD', 'DT', 'IN', 'JJ', 'MD', 'NN', 'NNS', 'PRP', 'RB', 'RBR', 'TO', 'VB', 'VBD', 'VBG', 'VBN', 'VBZ']

>>> possible_tags_counter = Counter({p:0 for p in possible_tags})
>>> possible_tags_counter
Counter({'NNS': 0, 'VBZ': 0, 'DT': 0, '(': 0, 'JJ': 0, 'VBD': 0, ')': 0, 'RB': 0, 'VBG': 0, 'RBR': 0, 'VB': 0, 'IN': 0, 'CC': 0, ',': 0, 'PRP': 0, 'CD': 0, 'VBN': 0, '.': 0, 'MD': 0, 'NN': 0, 'TO': 0})
```

To iterate through each tagged sentence and get the counts of POS:

```
>>> df['tagged_sent'].apply(lambda x: Counter(list(zip(*x))[1]))
0    {'NN': 3, 'IN': 1, 'TO': 1, 'DT': 1, 'JJ': 1}
1    {'NN': 3, 'VB': 3, 'PRP': 1, 'TO': 1, 'DT': 1,...
2    {')': 1, 'JJ': 6, 'NN': 11, 'CC': 1, 'NNS': 3,...
3    {'DT': 3, 'VB': 1, 'NN': 2, 'VBN': 1, 'NNS': 1...
Name: tagged_sent, dtype: object

>>> df['pos_counts'] = df['tagged_sent'].apply(lambda x: Counter(list(zip(*x))[1]))

>>> df['pos_counts']
0    {'NN': 3, 'IN': 1, 'TO': 1, 'DT': 1, 'JJ': 1}
1    {'NN': 3, 'VB': 3, 'PRP': 1, 'TO': 1, 'DT': 1,...
2    {')': 1, 'JJ': 6, 'NN': 11, 'CC': 1, 'NNS': 3,...
3    {'DT': 3, 'VB': 1, 'NN': 2, 'VBN': 1, 'NNS': 1...
Name: pos_counts, dtype: object

# Now we can add in the POS that don't appears in the sentence with 0 counts:

>>> def add_pos_with_zero_counts(counter, keys_to_add):
...     for k in keys_to_add:
...         counter[k] = counter.get(k, 0)
...     return counter
... 
>>> df['pos_counts'].apply(lambda x: add_pos_with_zero_counts(x, possible_tags))
0    {'VB': 0, 'IN': 1, 'PRP': 0, 'DT': 1, 'CC': 0,...
1    {'VB': 3, ')': 0, 'DT': 1, 'CC': 0, 'RB': 0, '...
2    {'VB': 0, ')': 1, 'JJ': 6, 'NN': 11, 'CC': 1, ...
3    {'VB': 1, 'IN': 2, 'PRP': 0, 'NN': 2, 'CC': 0,...
Name: pos_counts, dtype: object

>>> df['pos_counts_with_zero'] = df['pos_counts'].apply(lambda x: add_pos_with_zero_counts(x, possible_tags))
```

Now flatten the values into the list:

```
>>> df['pos_counts_with_zero'].apply(lambda x: [count for tag, count in sorted(x.most_common())])
0    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
1    [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 0, 0, ...
2    [1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 7, 6, 0, 11, 3, 0, 2, 1,...
3    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, ...
Name: pos_counts_with_zero, dtype: object

>>> df['sent_vector'] = df['pos_counts_with_zero'].apply(lambda x: [count for tag, count in sorted(x.most_common())])
```

Now you need to create a new matrix to store the BoW:

```
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame(df['sent_vector'].tolist)
>>> df2.columns = sorted(possible_tags)
```

And voila:

```
>>> df2
   (  )  ,  .  CC  CD  DT  IN  JJ  MD ...   NNS  PRP  RB  RBR  TO  VB  VBD  \
0  0  0  0  0   0   0   1   1   1   0 ...     0    0   0    0   1   0    0   
1  0  0  0  1   0   0   1   3   2   2 ...     1    1   0    0   1   3    0   
2  1  1  3  1   1   1   3   7   6   0 ...     3    0   2    1   0   0    1   
3  0  0  0  0   0   0   3   2   1   1 ...     1    0   1    0   0   1    0   

   VBG  VBN  VBZ  
0    0    0    0  
1    0    1    0  
2    1    2    1  
3    0    1    0  

[4 rows x 21 columns]
```

---

**In short:**

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

import pandas as pd

from nltk import word_tokenize, pos_tag

df = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv', delimiter=';')
df.columns = ['sent', 'tag']

tok_and_tag = lambda x: pos_tag(word_tokenize(x))

df['lower_sent'] = df['sent'].apply(str.lower)
df['tagged_sent'] = df['lower_sent'].apply(tok_and_tag)

possible_tags = sorted(set(list(zip(*chain(*df['tagged_sent'])))[1]))

def add_pos_with_zero_counts(counter, keys_to_add):
    for k in keys_to_add:
        counter[k] = counter.get(k, 0)
    return counter


# Detailed steps.
df['pos_counts'] = df['tagged_sent'].apply(lambda x: Counter(list(zip(*x))[1]))
df['pos_counts_with_zero'] = df['pos_counts'].apply(lambda x: add_pos_with_zero_counts(x, possible_tags))
df['sent_vector'] = df['pos_counts_with_zero'].apply(lambda x: [count for tag, count in sorted(x.most_common())])

# All in one.
df['sent_vector'] = df['tagged_sent'].apply(lambda x:
    [count for tag, count in sorted(
        add_pos_with_zero_counts(
            Counter(list(zip(*x))[1]), 
                    possible_tags).most_common()
         )
    ]
)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(df['sent_vector'].tolist())
df2.columns = possible_tags
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution and, what is more important, good explanation!

Comment: Glad that the answer helps ;P

Comment: Hi! One last question — I have tried to add also a tag column with label values (certain/uncertain) to the output but didn't find a proper way. Can you recommend something please?

Comment: Perhaps `df2['label'] = df['tag']`?

Comment: Oh right. Sorry for disturbing you. I was trying `df2 = df2 + df['tag']` and different variations what I could imagine from other programming languages but forgot about this approach. Thank you!