# POS Tags to Wordnet in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: pandas, nltk, wordnet, pos-tagger, lemmatization

I am using NLTK on a dataset stored as a pandas dataframe. All the raw text processing procedures worked fine until I tried to convert the Treebank POS tags to Wordnet POS tags. These are the codes which worked fine for me.

```
import pandas as pd
import string
from nltk import WordPunctTokenizer, pos_tag
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn, stopwords

# Example dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame([[2, "I am new at programming."],
                   [7, "Leaves are falling from the tree."],
                   [4, "Sophia has been studying since this morning."]], columns = ['ID', 'Text'])


# Tokenize text
tokenizer = nltk.WordPunctTokenizer()

df["Tokens"] = df["Text"].str.lower().apply(tokenizer.tokenize)


# Remove punctuations
pattern = string.punctuation

print(pattern)

def remove_punctuation(tokens):
    filtered = [word for word in tokens if word not in pattern]
    return filtered

df["Tokens"] = df["Tokens"].apply(remove_punctuation)


# Remove stopwords
stopwords = stopwords.words('english')

def remove_stopwords(tokens):
    filtered_words = [word for word in tokens if word not in stopwords]
    return filtered_words

df["Tokens"] = df["Tokens"].apply(remove_stopwords)
```

The following lines of codes did not work and I got this error:

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

```
def wordnet_pos(pos_tag):
    if pos_tag.startswith('J'):
        return wn.ADJ
    elif pos_tag.startswith('V'):
        return wn.VERB
    elif pos_tag.startswith('N'):
        return wn.NOUN
    elif pos_tag.startswith('R'):
        return wn.ADV
    else:
        return None

def wordnet(tokens):
    pos_tokens = [nltk.pos_tag(token) for token in tokens]
    pos_tokens = [(word, wordnet_pos(pos_tag)) for (word, pos_tag) in pos_tokens]
    return pos_tokens

df["Wordnet"] = df["Tokens"].apply(wordnet)
```

This is what I had hoped to achieve - to create `df["Wordnet"]` with the Wordnet POS tags.

```
print(df["Wordnet"])

0                     [(new, a), (programming, n)]
1           [(leaves, n), (falling, v), (tree, n)]
2    [(sophia, n), (studying, v), (since, n), (...
Name: Wordnet, dtype: object
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44088038/create-sentence-row-to-pos-tags-counts-column-matrix-from-a-dataframe/44088864#44088864

Comment: Anyone able to help?